# SonarQube Code Coverage Not Parsing for VB.net Framework Running on Azure DevOps

Tags: vb.net, sonarqube, .net-4.8

We are having a problem with SonarQube reporting code coverage in a VB.net framework project.  To troubleshoot, we created two simple projects.  One in C# and the other in VB.net.  The yaml files are identical except for the key and project name.  We noticed that a portion in the C# log is not in the VB.net log. We've been working this for a few weeks, and I am at my wits end.  Any help/recommendations would be appreciated.

yml:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: Default

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build

    pool:
      name: Default
      
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
      displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
      inputs:
        SonarQube: SonarQube
        projectKey: 'com.server.app.key:CSTest'
        projectName: CSTest

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        codeCoverageEnabled: true
        resultsFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\TestResults'

    # Run Code Analysis task
    - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
      displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'
      
    # Publish Quality Gate Result task
    - task: SonarQubePublish@5
      displayName: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'         
      inputs:
        pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

C# log excerpt:

```
2022-07-29T16:29:55.7585662Z ##[section]Starting: Run Code Analysis
2022-07-29T16:29:55.7852727Z ==============================================================================
2022-07-29T16:29:55.7853073Z Task         : Run Code Analysis
2022-07-29T16:29:55.7853367Z Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
2022-07-29T16:29:55.7853638Z Version      : 5.6.1
2022-07-29T16:29:55.7853803Z Author       : sonarsource
2022-07-29T16:29:55.7854358Z Help         : Version: 5.6.1. This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.
...
2022-07-29T16:30:31.4351017Z INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
2022-07-29T16:30:31.4560959Z INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
2022-07-29T16:30:31.4806371Z INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'C:\agent\_work\883\.sonarqube\out\0\output-cs'
2022-07-29T16:30:31.6816920Z INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'C:\agent\_work\883\.sonarqube\out\1\output-cs'
2022-07-29T16:30:31.7124947Z INFO: Importing 2 Roslyn reports
2022-07-29T16:30:31.7710077Z INFO: Found 2 MSBuild C# projects: 1 MAIN project. 1 TEST project.
2022-07-29T16:30:31.7711973Z INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=313ms
2022-07-29T16:30:31.7712604Z INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
2022-07-29T16:30:31.7714255Z INFO: Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report C:\agent\_work\883\s\TestResults\sa_vstsagent_BUILD01_2022-07-29_11_29_51\In\BUILD01\sa_vstsagent_BUILD01_2022-07-29.11_29_43.coveragexml
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3466313Z INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: C:\agent\_work\883\s\TestResults\sa_vstsagent_BUILD01_2022-07-29_11_29_51\In\BUILD01\sa_vstsagent_BUILD01_2022-07-29.11_29_43.coveragexml
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3887422Z INFO: Coverage Report Statistics: 2 files, 1 main files, 1 main files with coverage, 1 test files, 0 project excluded files, 0 other language files.
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3978290Z INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=593ms
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3978788Z INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp]
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3979274Z INFO: Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file 'C:\agent\_work\883\s\TestResults\sa_vstsagent_BUILD01_2022-07-29_11_29_51.trx'.**
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3979816Z INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=32ms
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3980153Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3980542Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3981345Z INFO: SCM Publisher SCM provider for this project is: git
2022-07-29T16:30:32.3981910Z INFO: SCM Publisher 4 source files to be analyzed
2022-07-29T16:30:32.6430256Z INFO: SCM Publisher 4/4 source files have been analyzed (done) | time=250ms
2022-07-29T16:30:32.6487517Z INFO: CPD Executor 1 file had no CPD blocks
2022-07-29T16:30:32.6488449Z INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 1 file
2022-07-29T16:30:32.6684874Z INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=31ms
2022-07-29T16:30:32.7929589Z INFO: Analysis report generated in 109ms, dir size=195 KB
2022-07-29T16:30:32.8509962Z INFO: Analysis report compressed in 47ms, zip size=37 KB
2022-07-29T16:30:33.2059818Z INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 359ms
2022-07-29T16:30:33.2253643Z INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://sonar.server.com/dashboard?id=com.optum.ushealth.ezapp%3ABleeTest
2022-07-29T16:30:33.2255193Z INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
2022-07-29T16:30:33.2256147Z INFO: More about the report processing at https://sonar.server.com/api/ce/task?id=AYJKy5eFKOMsnbNgrQMF
2022-07-29T16:30:33.2308279Z INFO: Executing post-job 'Forbidden Configuration Breaker'
2022-07-29T16:30:33.2309273Z INFO: Executing post-job 'Quality Gate Breaker'
2022-07-29T16:30:33.9715321Z INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
2022-07-29T16:30:44.0949296Z INFO: Quality gate status: OK
2022-07-29T16:30:44.1192765Z INFO: Analysis total time: 29.452 s
```

VB.net log excerpt:

```
2022-08-08T19:37:12.1253735Z ##[section]Starting: Run Code Analysis
2022-08-08T19:37:12.1520769Z ==============================================================================
2022-08-08T19:37:12.1521080Z Task         : Run Code Analysis
2022-08-08T19:37:12.1521338Z Description  : Run scanner and upload the results to the SonarQube server.
2022-08-08T19:37:12.1521612Z Version      : 5.6.1
2022-08-08T19:37:12.1521774Z Author       : sonarsource
2022-08-08T19:37:12.1522279Z Help         : Version: 5.6.1. This task is not needed for Maven and Gradle projects since the scanner should be run as part of the build.
...
2022-08-08T19:37:45.1924722Z INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
2022-08-08T19:37:45.2076380Z INFO: Sensor VB.NET [vbnet]
2022-08-08T19:37:45.2296786Z INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'C:\agent\_work\884\.sonarqube\out\0\output-vbnet'
2022-08-08T19:37:45.4456070Z INFO: Importing results from 5 proto files in 'C:\agent\_work\884\.sonarqube\out\1\output-vbnet'
2022-08-08T19:37:45.4933637Z INFO: Importing 2 Roslyn reports
2022-08-08T19:37:45.5374215Z INFO: Found 2 MSBuild VB.NET projects: 1 MAIN project. 1 TEST project.
2022-08-08T19:37:45.5374680Z INFO: Sensor VB.NET [vbnet] (done) | time=328ms
2022-08-08T19:37:45.5375031Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
2022-08-08T19:37:45.5688978Z INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=31ms
2022-08-08T19:37:45.5878564Z INFO: CPD Executor 1 file had no CPD blocks
2022-08-08T19:37:45.5883027Z INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 1 file
2022-08-08T19:37:45.6040291Z INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=15ms
2022-08-08T19:37:45.6128934Z INFO: Load New Code definition
2022-08-08T19:37:45.6619968Z INFO: Load New Code definition (done) | time=63ms
2022-08-08T19:37:45.7910875Z INFO: Analysis report generated in 188ms, dir size=196 KB
2022-08-08T19:37:45.8691353Z INFO: Analysis report compressed in 78ms, zip size=38 KB
2022-08-08T19:37:45.9781977Z INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 109ms
2022-08-08T19:37:45.9892794Z INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://sonar.server.com/dashboard?id=com.server.app.key%3AVBTest
2022-08-08T19:37:45.9893838Z INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
2022-08-08T19:37:45.9895367Z INFO: More about the report processing at https://sonar.server.com/api/ce/task?id=AYJ-9pZTKOMsnbNgr-Lp
2022-08-08T19:37:45.9926041Z INFO: Executing post-job 'Forbidden Configuration Breaker'
2022-08-08T19:37:45.9926715Z INFO: Executing post-job 'Quality Gate Breaker'
2022-08-08T19:37:46.6924343Z INFO: Waiting for report processing to complete...
2022-08-08T19:37:56.8460116Z INFO: Quality gate status: OK
2022-08-08T19:37:56.8693669Z INFO: Analysis total time: 25.703 s
```

Comment: The part in the C# log that is missing from the VB log starts at 2022-07-29T16:30:31.7714255 and goes through 2022-07-29T16:30:32.3978788 and deals with parsing.